# Strapi CKEditor shows MediaLib image for richtext field

Tags: ckeditor, strapi

Using the CKEditor with strapi to allow rich-text fields, some work great while others are rendering as MediaLib uploads only.

Here's the content type in Strapi:

[image]

And here's how it renders:

[image]

I add them the same way as any text field:

[image]

My versions are:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the full ckeditor field to show back up was a complete rebuild of the code from the source. There wasn't anything missing or changed from this, so I'm not sure if this is cache related or not but this is worrisome if it can reappear.